How to show Compose drop down menu where ever a user taps on the screen when using ComposeView in XML Layout
I am investigating the use of androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView in my current android project.
I am attempting to show a compose androidx.compose.material3.DropdownMenu where ever a user taps on the device screen.
here is my xml layout with androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/second_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SecondActivity">

    <androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
        android:id="@+id/composeDropDownMenuOuter"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_gravity="end|top"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/showDropDown"
        android:text="Show Drop Down"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


heres my onCreate function

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second)

        var showDropDownMenu = false

        findViewById<Button>(R.id.showDropDown).setOnClickListener {
            showDropDownMenu = !showDropDownMenu
            println("wah Hay!!! $showDropDownMenu")
        }

        findViewById<ComposeView>(R.id.composeDropDownMenuOuter).apply {
            setViewCompositionStrategy(ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnViewTreeLifecycleDestroyed)
            setContent {
                val showIt by remember { mutableStateOf(showDropDownMenu) }
                DropdownHotspotButton(showIt)
            }
        }
    }


how can i transform the motion events captured below into a flow the dropdownmenu can employ to position itself correctly

   override fun onTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        return when (event.action) {
            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Action was DOWN")
                true
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Action was MOVE")
                true
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Action was UP")
                true
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL -> {
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Action was CANCEL")
                true
            }
            MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE -> {
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Movement occurred outside bounds of current screen element")
                true
            }
            else -> super.onTouchEvent(event)
        }
    }


i believe i need to first pass the user tap locations to the compose view, have the compose
I cannot see how to achieve this
